# How to create a table with two internal embedded imgclass items with different opacities?

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I need to complete an assignment for a Web App Dev course I'm taking. The instructions are:

1. Include a reference to the CSS sheet you created (done)
2. Add the title styles (done)
3. Add a page heading  "Having Fun with Styles" (done)
4. Place some text in a paragraph block (done)
5. Add a table with two rows and three columns
6. Place the same image to each cell in the first row
7. Enter 25% Opacity, 50% Opacity, and 100% Opacity in the second row
8. Create two internal (embedded) imgclass styles “a" One will be class
   “a” the other class “b.”
9. Set the opacity for “a” to .25 (dot 25) and “b” to .50 (dot 50)
10. Update the first image in the table to the img class "a" style
11. Set the second image in the table to the img class "b" style
12. Change the color style for the h1 element to teal.
13. Make the width style of the p element to 50% using the in-line style.

I need help with #5, 6, and 8.

I tried putting the below code and cannot get the pictures to display.

```
<div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> <th> a </th> <th> b </th> <th> c </th></tr>
<style type= "text/css">
.imga {width 300px; height:238px; opacity:.25}
.imgb {width 300px; height:238px; opacity:.50}
<img class= "a" src= "tiger.jpg">
<img class= "b" src= "tiger.jpg">
</style>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<hr>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Styles</title>


</head>
<body>
<h1>Having Fun with Styles</h1>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nullam id orci elementum, interdum velit eget, congue felis. 
Sed erat odio, semper finibus nisl quis, congue auctor est. 
Curabitur accumsan mi in leo tincidunt eleifend.             
</p>

<div>
<table> 



<tbody>
<tr> <th>a </th> <th>b </th> <th> c</th> </tr>
<style type= "text/css">
.imga {width 300px; height:238px; opacity:.25}
.imgb {width 300px; height:238px; opacity:.50}
<img class= "a" src= "tiger.jpg">
<img class= "b" src= "tiger.jpg">
</style>


</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<hr>
</html>
```

I expected the pictures to display, but none of them do.
I see h1 displayed with the correct color from my CSS file, the paragraph text, the background color changed by the CSS, and the horizontal line rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number #5, #6, and #8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Styles</title>

<style>
    .a {
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
    .b {
        opacity: 0.50;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Having Fun with Styles</h1>

<p> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nullam id orci elementum, interdum velit eget, congue felis. 
Sed erat odio, semper finibus nisl quis, congue auctor est. 
Curabitur accumsan mi in leo tincidunt eleifend.             
</p>

<table> 
<tbody>
    <tr> <!-- Row 1 -->
        <td>
            <img class= "a" src= "tiger.jpg">
        </td> 
        <td> 
            <img class= "b" src= "tiger.jpg">
        </td> 
        <td> 
            <img src= "tiger.jpg">
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Row 2 -->
        <td style="opacity: 0.25;">
            Cell 2,1
        </td> 
        <td style="opacity: 0.50;"> 
            Cell 2,2 
        </td> 
        <td style="opacity: 1;"> 
            Cell 2,3
        </td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```